# Patch standard package

Tags: go

I want to replace some function from standard Go library (`os.Exit` specifically). Can I do that? I tried:

```
myExitValue := reflect.ValueOf(func() {
    fmt.Println("exiting")
})
reflect.ValueOf(os.Exit).Set(myExitValue)
```

But it panics: `reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value`

Comment: https://github.com/bouk/monkey. Don't do it though.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. What is your actual situation?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks to [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/bouk/monkey"
)

func myExit(code int) {
    _ = code
    fmt.Println(`I think you shouldn't exit.`)
}

func init() {
    monkey.Patch(os.Exit, myExit)
}

func main() {
    os.Exit(1)
    fmt.Println(`But why?`)
}
```

Comment: Per the top of the docs for that package: "This is as unsafe as it sounds and I don't recommend anyone do it outside of a testing environment." This can also cause unpredictable behavior in any code that expects `os.Exit` to work the way it does in its documentation.

Comment: The "safe" (aside from the risks of modifying a fundamental call like `os.Exit`) way to change the std lib behavior, is to just build a patched version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do is achievable even with help of Reflect library. By calling Go's function/method from another package, you are calling **a copy** of the original code.

You would have to either make wrapper function which somehow changes original behavior, which is cleaner and better way of handling for this kind of purposes. E.g.:

```
// Do stuff what you need.
func ExitLog(message string) {
   fmt.Printf("an error occured with message: '%s'", message)
   os.Exit(1)
}
```

and call the function instead of the original one.

**Edit:** Someone in the comments mentioned a library for doing such a thing, but please reconsider your intention. Rewriting package's behavior by hacking it is not considered clean and/or good practice.

**Edit2:** If you are trying to send a message whenever an error occurs, take a look at publish-subscribe pattern:

- https://hackernoon.com/communicating-go-applications-through-redis-pub-sub-messaging-paradigm-df7317897b13
- https://flaviocopes.com/golang-event-listeners/